# lvalue required as left operand of assignment at line 20

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me to fix the error please.
Here's the code:

The code should find all off the number in a string from a file, then find the biggest 3 digits number without changing the order of the numbers.
But when I tried to run the program, the error appear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    string a;
    ifstream input ("D:\\C++\\Tim so\\Bai1\\input.inp");
    fstream output ("D:\\C++\\Tim so\\Bai1\\output.out", ios::out);
    input >> a;
    int temp, temp1;
    vector<string> arr;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length();i++)
    {
        /*LINE 20*/ if (a[i] = "0"|| a[i] = "1"|| a[i] = "2"|| a[i] = "3"|| a[i]="4"|| a[i] = "5"|| a[i] = "6"|| a[i] = "7"|| a[i] = "8"|| a[i] = "9")
        {
            arr.push_back(a[i]);
        }
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < arr.capacity(); n++)
    {
        if (arr[n] < arr[n-1])
        {
            temp1 = arr[n];
            temp = n;   
        } 
    }
    cout << temp1;
    for (int k = temp1; k < arr.capacity(); k++)
    {
        if (arr[k] < arr[k-1])
        {
            temp1 = arr[k];
            temp = k;   
        } 
    }
    cout << temp1;
    for (int j = temp1; j < arr.capacity(); j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] < arr[j-1])
        {
            temp1 = arr[j];
            temp = j;   
        } 
    }
    cout << temp1;
}
```

Comment: If you want to refer to a line number you need to number your lines.

Comment: But don't actually number the lines. Do what xaxxon did and mark the line with a comment. If you put line numbers in, people have to remove those line numbers in order to compile your code.

Comment: @user4581301 it's kinda silly that SO doesn't put the line numbers beside code fragments automatically for you... or at least give you a button to press to put the line numbers in .

Comment: Suggestion: naming a vector `arr` may be slightly misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `a[i] = "0"` with `a[i] == '0'` etc.

`=` is assignment, `==` is equaity check.

`'...'` is a character constant of type *char*. Elements of an std::string are characters of type *char*.

`"..."` is a string literal of type `char[...]` (array of characters).

Comment: But then when I run it appear: [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]. Still in line 20

Comment: @Bruh Let us apply pts's solution to the entire line, not just the first test: https://godbolt.org/z/hadxEcqro . There are no more errors on line 20. That said, take a good, long look at [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). Still many more errors to be fixed, so have at thee!

Comment: @Bruh [here's your code after a quick inspection](https://godbolt.org/z/hfb5c3xff). I have added comments to explain what I changed and why. Some places I point out a problem without fixing it because they are logic problems rather than gaps in understanding, and the sort of things you need to learn to deal with yourself.